# How to build a grouped queue system with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, queue

I am trying to make a queue system that consists of multiple queues for "titles".

```js
import { Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';

enum Title {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  C = 'c',
}

type Queue = { [key: string]: User[] };
type TitleHolders = { [key: string]: User };
type Timers = { [key: string]: Subject<null> };

const HOLDING_TIME = 10_000;
const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
const stamp = () => new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
const log = (data: unknown) => console.log(stamp(), JSON.stringify(data));
const fetchTitle = (title: Title) =>
  sleep(10_000).then(() => ({ success: true }));

class User {
  title: Title | undefined;

  constructor(public name: string) {}

  toString() {
    return `${this.name}: '${this.title}'`;
  }
}

class TitleManager {
  #queue: Queue = {};
  #currentHolders: TitleHolders = {};
  #timers: Timers = {};

  #setTitle(t: Title) {
    if (this.#currentHolders[t]) {
      return;
    }
    const user = this.#queue[t].pop();
    const sub = new Subject<null>();
    sub.subscribe({
      complete: () => {
        const title = user.title;
        delete this.#currentHolders[title];
        delete this.#timers[user.name];
        user.title = undefined;
        log(`>>> '${t}' title REMOVED from ${user.name}`);
        if (this.#queue[title].length) this.#setTitle(title);
      },
    });
    this.#currentHolders[t] ??= user;
    this.#timers[user.name] = sub;
    user.title = t;
    log(`>>> '${t}' title ADDED to ${user.name}`);
    timer(HOLDING_TIME).subscribe(() => sub.complete());
  }

  async giveTitleToUser(t: Title, u: User) {
    this.#queue[t] ??= [];
    this.#queue[t].push(u);
    console.log('starting title request for', u.name);
    const { success } = await fetchTitle(t);
    // Return success status, only set title if if fetching was successful
    if (success) {
      this.#setTitle(t);
    }
  }

  removeUsersTitle(u: User) {
    this.#timers[u.name].complete();
  }
}

const titleManager = new TitleManager();

(async function () {
  const leela = new User('Leela');
  const fry = new User('Fry');

  await titleManager.giveTitleToUser(Title.A, leela);
  await titleManager.giveTitleToUser(Title.A, fry);
})();

(async function () {
  const bender = new User('Bender');

  await sleep(500);
  await titleManager.giveTitleToUser(Title.B, bender);
})();
```

[Link to playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hvtq91?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

The queue should only be able to process 1 `fetchTitle` call at a time. Only when it's finished it should run the next one. I am struggling to figure out how I could achieve this. Currently you can see in the logs that it starts 2 requests for `fetchTitle` without 1 request finishing. It would also be nice if I could return the success status to the caller side but I don't know if this is possible at all.

Comment: Just remove your async/await calls. This will force each to happen sequentially rather than in series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on this:

```js
const userClaimsTitle$$ = new Subject<{ username: string; title: string }>();

userClaimsTitle$$
  .pipe(
    groupBy(({ username }) => username),
    mergeMap((group$) =>
      group$.pipe(
        concatMap(({ title, username }) =>
          concat(
            from(mockFetchTitle(title)).pipe(
              map(() => ({ title, username, type: 'ADDED' } as const))
            ),
            timer(10000).pipe(
              map(() => ({ title, username, type: 'REMOVED' } as const))
            )
          ).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))
        )
      )
    ),
    scan((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr.type === 'REMOVED') {
        const copy = { ...acc };
        delete copy[curr.username];
        return copy;
      }

      return { ...acc, [curr.username]: curr.title };
    }, {} as { [username: string]: string })
  )
```

Titles are grouped per person. Errors are managed properly. Titles are removed from their own queue 10s after being successfully fetched. You get the global current state at the end, to be able to display it in a UI.

Here's a **[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ue5sjj?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)** and the kind of output I get:

```
08:19:28 Queueing title a for User-A
08:19:28 Fetching title a for User-A
08:19:28 Queueing title a for User-B
08:19:28 Fetching title a for User-B
08:19:28 Queueing title b for User-A
08:19:33 Title a ADDED for User-A
08:19:33 Global state: {"User-A":"a"}
08:19:33 Title a ADDED for User-B
08:19:33 Global state: {"User-A":"a","User-B":"a"}
08:19:43 Title a REMOVED for User-A
08:19:43 Global state: {"User-B":"a"}
08:19:43 Fetching title b for User-A
08:19:43 Title a REMOVED for User-B
08:19:43 Global state: {}
08:19:48 Title b ADDED for User-A
08:19:48 Global state: {"User-A":"b"}
08:19:58 Title b REMOVED for User-A
08:19:58 Global state: {}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the complexity (I think) lies in the part where `mockFetchTitle` can only run once at a time in general, not per queue

Comment: Gotcha. How about this then: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pkt2ve?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: This is perfect in terms of the fetching happening only once at a time,  however this log seems off: `Global state: {"User-A":"a","User-B":"a"}` because a title can only be held by 1 user at a time

Comment: "a title can only be held by 1 user at a time". Does this mean that you could have `{"User-A":"a","User-B":"B"}`? So you can still have multiple people holding titles at the same time, but titles are "unique" and can only be held by 1 person at a time?

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: If you groupBy title instead of person in my previous stackblitz, does it gives you what you expect?

Comment: Grouping by title instead of person works fine indeed. How would this work for the user having a title be able to cancel the timeout though? I don't think the way I did it in my question works well for your solution

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jkhywh?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, it's working now

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to access the success status of `mockFetchTitle` at the caller side so I know when to display a cancel button if needed?

Comment: The next is synchronous, the workflow is asynchronous. So you can't do that. One option would be to generate a unique ID, pass it in the `next` call and then you could on the main observable watch when this ID is processed